# C# OData4 WebApi fails on expand of navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata, navigation-properties

I am working on creating a new web API that implements OData 4. I want to be able to select/expand on navigation properties, but I'm getting an error that I don't know how to resolve.

I've posted the request uri, response error, sample code, and the stack trace below. If you look at the code, "Phones" are clearly a method rather than a property like Id and Name, but I would think that I should be able to select and expand on the results of that method exactly like the properties.

What can I do to allow users of the API to select the values that are returned from that method?

*P.S. Navigation property may not be the correct name(?)*

**REQUEST URI**

```
http://localhost:10013/Call?$select=*&$expand=Phones
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{
    "error" : {
        "code" : "",
        "message" : "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Phones' on type 'Call'.",
        "innererror" : {
            "message" : "Could not find a property named 'Phones' on type 'Call'.",
            "type" : "Microsoft.OData.ODataException"
        }
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
public class CallController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Call> GetCall(ODataQueryOptions options)
    {
        return DatabaseContext.Call.GetAll();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Call
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Phone> Phones()
    {
        //just an example
        var list = new List<Phone>();
        return list as IEnumerable<Phone>
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**STACK TRACE**

1. Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.GenerateExpandItem(ExpandTermToken tokenIn)
2. System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
3. System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
4. System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
5. Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(ExpandToken tokenIn)
6. Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Bind(ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo, ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)
7. Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo)
   Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpand()
8. System.Web.OData.Query.Validators.SelectExpandQueryValidator.Validate(SelectExpandQueryOption selectExpandQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
9. System.Web.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
10. System.Web.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
11. System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
12. System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
13. System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ODataQueryContext queryContext)
14. System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have created function called Phones in the class Call. Please convert that function to property as below:

public IEnumerable Phones {get;set;}

Comment: I understand that would work, is it possible to do it without converting it?

Comment: As you might be aware, there is difference in Function and Property. OData can recognize Property/Attribute of a model to expose as a respone in json/xml/atom but with function it won't be.